# Css select: when style is applied doesn't display a picked dropdown option

Tags: html, css, dropdown, html-select

I have a dropdown list that I added a little of CSS styles to.
After it the picked dropdow options stopped being displayed:

```
<select class="form-dropdown form-input"
        id="genders" name="gender" >
  <option value="">Choose gender</option>

  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

```
.form-input  {
    height: 2vw;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 15px;
 }
```

[image]

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zufcL1j4/).

How do I fix it?

Comment: Adjust your height and padding values, they are conflicting. Remove height for ex and check

Comment: @AnuragSrivastave Thank you, it worked!